# How to load .data extension into R? What is the encoding?

Tags: r

I am trying to load this dataset into R: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data

but I have never seen a .data extension before! I did come across another answer on StackOverflow which suggested something along the lines of:

```
f <-file("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data", open="r" ,encoding="UTF-16")
data <- read.table(f, dec=",", header=T)
```

but I don't think that the encoding is correct. How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a question for stackoverflow. But read the agaricus-lepiota.names file, and you will get your answer. It is simply a csv file, with no header. `read.csv(f)` and all the columns are described in the mentioned file which can be found [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/)

Comment: You can just use `data <- read.table("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data", sep=",")`. `encoding=` has to do with the character encoding used to translate bytes to letters. Since this file only seems to use ASCII characters, the encoding does not need to be changed from the default. There's no formal format known as a `.data` format. You can put whatever extension you want on a file, what really matters is how the data inside is formatted. Either that will be documented or you'll just have to manually inspect the contents.

Comment: @Oliver - was that comment necesssary? Why isn't it a question for stackoverflow? I have looked at that page and I wouldn't know how to open up the .names file either since my computer doesn't recognize the extension.

Comment: In practice this question had nothing to do with programming, or software development, which is the target for stackoverflow. Nothing negative meant by my comment, simply stating the guidelines of SO.